# Receiving Messages Sent Through GCM in Android Version 4.0.4

Tags: android, android-intent, google-cloud-messaging

After sending  message through http. I am not able to receive message on android device version 4.0.4. Its firing OnReceive() method when debugging enabled  but intent having action com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION , it should be com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE.
So i am not able to get message. Rest all versions its working fine.

My Android.Manifest file code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="auto" package="hellomultiscreen" android:versionCode="11" android:versionName="2.2.0" >
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <permission android:name="hellomultiscreen.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="hellomultiscreen.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <application android:label="Online Booking" >

    <!-- Only C2DM servers can send messages for the app. If permission is not set - any other app can generate it -->
        <receiver android:name="hellomultiscreen.MyGCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <!-- Receive the actual message -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RETRY" />
                <category android:name="hellomultiscreen" />
            </intent-filter>

        </receiver>
    <service android:name="hellomultiscreen.MyIntentService" enabled="true" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk />
</manifest>
```

and BroadCastReceiver File where OnReceive() Method Succesfully firing after sending message thorugh GCM is(Here Getting Intent-Action Registration instead of RECEIVE)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace hellomultiscreen
{

    public class MyGCMBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {

        const string TAG = "PushHandlerBroadcastReceiver";
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {

            MyIntentService.RunIntentInService(context, intent);
            SetResult(Result.Ok, null, null);
            Toast.MakeText(context, "Received Message!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this receiver

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```